# MySQL Trigger - Update data before inserting

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that changes a date on input to a unix timestamp.
When i insert a value to the table the inserted value is NULL

```
CREATE TRIGGER `updateDate` BEFORE INSERT ON  `tl_calendar_events` 
FOR EACH
ROW SET NEW.startDate = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(NEW.startDate, '%d.%m.%Y'))
```

The input value for 'startDate' is like 01.11.2013

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tl_calendar_events` (
...
`startDate` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `pid` (`pid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=66 ;
```

Comment: please post your table creation query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the data type of `startDate` column to varchar, then your above query will work. Use

```
`startDate` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL in your table creation query
```

OR

you can change data type to `DATE` or `DATETIME` and do the conversion to unix time in your program in that case there is no need for that trigger

Comment: @benfolds - If you end up storing dates as `VARCHAR`, you deserve having to deal with data like `2013-02-31` or `do not know`.

Comment: Agree, it is better to store date as is (DATE, DATETIME or INT for UNIX timestamp).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert strings into INT column. It looks like STRICT server mode is off and default values are inserted (...`startTime int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL`...).

The only way is to change these values when they are being inserted, e.g. -

```
INSERT INTO tl_calendar_events(startDate)
  VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('01.11.2013', '%d.%m.%Y')));
```

Comment: If I understood it correctly, `NEW.startDate` is not allowed to be a string in the first place because the column is numeric, not even in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. Before the triggers runs, MySQL creates `NEW.startDate` as `INT` variable, thus the *Data truncated* error you get in strict mode.